# How do i send response back to Gateway interface?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

im currently getting this error :

```
 DestinationResolutionException: 
     no output-channel or replyChannel header available .
```

I  have a file gateway that is injected in a controller

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface FileGateway {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "router.input", replyChannel = "output")
    FileRequestResponse requestFile(FileRequestRequest fileFetchRequest);
}
```

and a router that send messages to respective channels

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow routeFileRequest() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("router.input")
            .<FileRequestRequest, FileType>route(m -> m.getParameters().getFileType(), m -> m
                    .channelMapping(FileType.CONTRACT, "contract.transform")
                    .channelMapping(FileType.INVOICE, "invoice.tranform"))
            // .channelMapping(FileType.USAGE, "usageChannel"))
            .get();
}
```

Here my transformer bean , converts message to string and sends to contract.input channel  , i can see in my logs that message arrives contract,input channel , however after response in handler method i get:

```
org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException:
    no output-channel or replyChannel header available.
```

Transformer:

```
@Transformer(inputChannel = "contract.transform", outputChannel = "contract.input")
public Message<String> transformContractMessage(Message<FileRequestRequest> request) {
    /**
     *
     *  @param request
     *  @return contractId
     */
    FileRequestRequest frr = request.getPayload();

    return MessageBuilder.
            withPayload(request.
                    getPayload().getContractId()).
            setHeader("fileType", "CONTRACT").build();
}
```

Below is the service activator to send message back to router.output , however i encounter that exception above .

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "contract.input" ,outputChannel = "output")
public FileRequestResponse res(Message<String> message){
    log.info(" Retrieving File With Contract ID {} ",message.getPayload());
    ContractRsp contractResponse = contractFetchService.retrieveContract(message.getPayload());
    log.info(" Contract File Received {} ",contractResponse);

    return FileRequestResponse.builder().build();
}
@Bean
public DirectChannel output(){
    DirectChannel channel = new DirectChannel();

    return channel;
}
```

My aim here is to get message back to FileGateway interface after response .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gateway is a request-reply component and for correlation between them a `replyChannel`  header with a `TemporaryReplyChannel` is populated during sending a message into a `requestChannel`.

This is clearly explained in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#gateway-default-reply-channel).

So, even if you provide that `replyChannel = "output"` and use it somewhere downstream, a `replyChannel` must preserve in the headers.

Your problem code is here in the `@Transformer`:

```
return MessageBuilder.
        withPayload(request.
                getPayload().getContractId()).
        setHeader("fileType", "CONTRACT").build();
```

You build a new message and don't copy request header to curry that `replyChannel`.

Unlike many other components (e.g. `@ServiceActivator`), a transformer doesn't copy headers into a reply message if a `Message` instance is returned from the transformation function.

So, you need to consider to add into your code over there this: `copyHeaders(request.getHeaders())`

Comment: Well, you need to return from that transformer method just a `payload` or message but with copied request headers.